# Pjsip java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: for armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, pjsip

I am trying to build **libpjsua2.so** using **armeabi-v7a** architecture type.

Here are the steps I followed:

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android

I just changed TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags and rest everything kept as it is.

It worked well with **arm64-v8a** and I am able to run project on **Google Pixel**.

When I build **armeabi-v7a**, I didn't receive any errors but when I run the project on **Nexus 5**, it gives me the following error:

> 08-09 16:52:01.625 19296-19296/com.pjdroid.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.pjdroid.sample, PID: 19296
>       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__aeabi_memclr8" referenced by "/data/app/com.pjdroid.sample-1/lib/arm/libpjsua2.so"...
>           at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
>           at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
>           at com.pjdroid.sample.MyApp.(MyApp.java:278)
>           at com.pjdroid.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I tried several times make clean and remove everything but every time I received this error.

I think there's some issue in creating this file for armeabi-v7a.

Can you suggest me if I am doing anything wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation. This is what the [PJSIP getting started guide](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) has to say (almost at the bottom)

> UnsatisfiedLinkError exception with "cannot locate 'rand'" message.
>
> As described ​here, this happens if you've built your native components with the android-21 target, but are trying to run it on a device with an older Android version, so re-run configure with APP_PLATFORM set to lower platform version, e.g:
> APP_PLATFORM=android-19 ./configure-android